# Is it more efficient to use addEventListener, or onclick for performance?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript only, without jQuery.

```
<div onclick="doFunction()"></div>
<div onclick="doFunction()"></div>
<div onclick="doFunction()"></div>
<div onclick="doFunction()"></div>
<div onclick="doFunction()"></div>
<div onclick="doFunction()"></div>
```

vs

```
document.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: I expect the difference to be so incredibly minimal that it isn't even worth thinking about unless you have tens of thousands of DOM elements with onClick handlers (in which case, your site isn't going to work for other reasons). Do whichever one is more expressive to you.

Comment: This is called "micro-optimization" and is considered a pointless task. If you want to choose between methods, do it because it makes your code better, easier to understand, easier to maintain. When you discover that your approach is causing a problem with performance, fix it. Until then, concentrate on writing correct code, not on unmeasured performance problems that are probably non-problems.

Comment: addEventListener is much better in terms of performance than onclick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

addEventListner will be faster when compared to onclick. You can check the below link for performance details by running tests.

http://jsperf.com/click-vs-addeventlistener/9

For more details on using those, you can check the following link.

[addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: Seem very browser specific: in Chrome `addEventListener` is much faster but in Firefox it's the `onclick`.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and its onclick which is faster than addEventListener. Faster by 1 operation only though. Which means they almost the same in terms of speed.

Comment: Mirror: https://jsperf.app/click-vs-addeventlistener/22

Answer (score 5):

1. By using "onclick" you are mixing Javascript and HTML which is not
   considered a good practice as it is not scalable. Consider adding, inserting, deleting elements in your example dynamically.
   HTML describes the structure, CSS describes the styling and JavaScript controls the behavior.
2. If you haven't looked at
   [Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate): Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to specific nodes instead eventlistener is added to one parent.

Hence `addEventListener` with *event delegation* would be way to go

Comment: I suspect they downvoted because you didn't answer the question with respect to performance - though you're right in most cases, `addEventListener` with event delegation would be way to go